# Changing the value of a nested dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, key

I have a nested dictionary in this format

```
{'U_1003076': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+34100325_X+sp': {'label': 1}, 'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240243X+sp': {'label': 1}}, 'U_1019796': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240184+sp': {'label': 1}}
```

How do I change it to this

```
{'U_1003076': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+34100325_X+sp': 1}, 'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240243X+sp': 1}, 'U_1019796': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240184+sp': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a recursive function

So go through the dictionary and check whether the value for some key is also a dictionary, if it is, call the function again, else check whether the key is `"label"` then call the function again on the value an return it

```
my_dict = {
    "U_1003076": {
        "C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 34100325_X sp": {"label": 1},
        "C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 30240243X sp": {"label": 1},
    },
    "U_1019796": {"C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 30240184 sp": {"label": 1}},
}
def solution(my_dict):
    if type(my_dict) is not dict: return my_dict
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            my_dict[k]=solution(v)
        elif k=="label":
            return solution(v)
    return my_dict

print(solution(my_dict))
```

```
{
    "U_1003076": {
        "C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 34100325_X sp": 1,
        "C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 30240243X sp": 1,
    },
    "U_1019796": {"C_course-v1:TsinghuaX 30240184 sp": 1},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive approach:

```
def recurse(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if 'label' in v.keys():
            d[k] = v['label']
        else:
            recurse(v)
    return d

>>> d = {'U_1003076': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+34100325_X+sp': {'label': 1},
     'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240243X+sp': {'label': 1}},
     'U_1019796': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240184+sp': {'label': 1}}}

>>> recurse(d)
{'U_1003076': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+34100325_X+sp': 1,
  'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240243X+sp': 1},
 'U_1019796': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240184+sp': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a one line list-comprehension to iterate over the nested dicts and use `dict.get()` to get its values for 'label' key at the last level.

```
expected = {k:{i:j.get('label') for i,j in v.items()} for k,v in nested.items()}
print(expected)
```

```
{'U_1003076': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+34100325_X+sp': 1,
  'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240243X+sp': 1},
 'U_1019796': {'C_course-v1:TsinghuaX+30240184+sp': 1}}
```

The advantage of using `dict.get()` is that if `label` is not found as key, it will return `None` instead of throwing an error. You can also set a default value to it incase key is not found. More details [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get).